# Why cinnamon and linux mint 19 do not hide my folders?

Tags: linux-mint

I have a laptop with SSD Hard and install Linux mint 19 with the cinnamon desktop manager on it. and set adapta-Nokoto theme. now when I am trying to hide a folder by adding a **.** to start of my folder name does not work and my folder is still visible in the file manager.

Comment: I did not understand your mean

Comment: it does not work for me

Comment: On virtually all file managers, including Nemo, viewing hidden files is a setting you can toggle on and off, and it is readily accessible because it is a commonly used option.  You can typically do it with a keyboard shortcut, but it is also a control that is a toolbar icon or menu item.  If you don't want to see hidden files, you just toggle it off.  That said, I'm using 19.1 Cinnamon and Nemo is hosed, at this point it won't even open and I just installed Dolphin (KDE's file manager, available in repository).  So if the issue is that the toggle doesn't work, it may be a general Nemo problem.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski ``` ctrl + H ``` worked!!! thankes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On virtually all file managers, including Nemo (official file manager of the Cinnamon desktop environment), viewing hidden files is a setting you can toggle on and off, and it is readily accessible because it is a commonly used option. You can typically do it with a keyboard shortcut, but it is also a control that is a toolbar icon or menu item. If you don't want to see hidden files, you just toggle it off.

In Nemo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> should toggle the option. Other managers may use other keyboard shortcuts (e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>).