# Two .bashrc files in my home dir

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-18.04, bashrc

I'm using Ubuntu on Windows and I was attempting to modify my .bashrc file to add a directory to my PATH variable. I used redirection to do it like so:

```
pwd >> ~/.bashrc
```

Now I have two .bashrc files in my home directory, and I can't get that back down to one. I've tried the following:

```
mv .bashrc copy.bashrc
rm .bashrc
```

That `mv` command successfully breaks them up so that `ls -a` shows one .bashrc and one copy.bashrc file, where the copy is the real one. That `rm` command, however, doesn't work and instead tells me that .bashrc doesn't exist.

I considered deleting copy.bashrc instead, but then I would lose everything that's supposed to be in .bashrc. I've also tried the following:

```
cat copy.bashrc > .bashrc
```

This simply leads me back to where I started with two .bashrc files in one directory.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

`pwd > ~/.bashrc` *overwrote* the .bashrc file in your home directory. This operation is not reversible and will not have created a second .bashrc (in fact having two files with the same name in a directory is *impossible*).

`mv .bashrc copy.bashrc` *moves* .bashrc to copy.bashrc, which means that the subsequent `rm .bashrc` will definitely fail - the file has been moved away and there is no longer a .bashrc file.

Another point of confusion is that `.bashrc` is the *full name* of the file. So if you by "two .bashrc files" mean that you have two files whose name end with ".bashrc" that's weird but not actually a problem - only the one named literally and only ".bashrc" will be used when starting your shell. There is not supposed to be any prefix to it, because it is not a file extension (extensions are anyway mostly meaningless, more so in *nix systems than on Windows).

Does that clarify things?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I already knew all of this, but you did help me to realize that I accidentally wrote `pwd > ~/.bashrc` in my question when I mean `pwd >> ~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

`.bashrc` as a string contains only printable characters from the ASCII set. If there was any common unprintable character, then `ls -a` would show it to you one way or another (I mean `ls` in Ubuntu, in general this depends on implementation), so you would already know.

But there are [Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19212345/10765659) non-ASCII characters that look like ASCII (or may look, depending on the font used). E.g. these three strings are pairwise different:

```
.bashrc
.bаshrc
.bashrс
```

Ubuntu should have no problem creating files with these names on any modern Linux filesystem. You can test it (hint: in an empty directory, so it's easy to `rm -r` it as a whole later):

```
touch .bashrc .bаshrc .bashrс; ls -a
```

The first one is what you would expect. The second one uses [this letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_(Cyrillic)) instead of ASCII `a`. The third one uses [this letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Es_(Cyrillic)) instead of ASCII `c`. It's quite obvious one can easily create yet another impostor – with these two non-ASCII letters.

Then there are "uncommon" unprintable characters `ls` would not show to you. This command (in Bash)

```
touch $'.bas\xE2\x80\x8Ehrc'
```

creates yet another impostor (with [left-to-right mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark)). For this file all characters you see in the output of `ls -a` are ASCII characters. You need like `ls -a | xxd` to spot what hides inside the name.

So this is one possible answer to "what is going on here?"

---

It's virtually impossible your first command created the impostor file, unless

- you had copied the command from somewhere,
- or your keyboard settings are weird (but then the string `.bashrc` you typed here on Super User would probably be affected; I have checked it's ASCII).

I suspect the extra file was already there, unnoticed. Maybe because of

- a prank,
- or some rogue software,
- or some other not-entirely-ASCII code you had copied, pasted and executed.

---

If you can see the file in your GUI file manager ([hint](https://superuser.com/a/1429450/432690)) or `mc`, then use its features to peek into / move / delete the troublesome file.

Or you can build a glob pattern that catches just the two files, temporarily move the real `.bashrc` to another directory and use the pattern to refer to the sole impostor. Few ideas:

```
ls .b?shr?
ls .*b*a*s*h*r*c*
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This imposter character thing seems probable. I didn't copy+paste the original command that generated the problem file, but I use four different keyboards. Unfortunately, regardless of which I use, can can't target the problem file with `cat .bashrc` or `ls -a .bashrc` or anything. In fact, even `ls -a *.*` doesn't list the file, even though `ls -a` still does. I tried `mc`, but it doesn't seem to work right for the Windows version of Ubuntu, which also means I don't have a GUI. I also tried `ls -a | xxd` but I don't understand what the output is telling me.

Comment: I also tried `ls -a *.*` with all four keyboards to make sure that it wasn't a weird `.` character or something, but no luck.

Comment: Try `ls -a | LC_ALL=C cat -vet` and see what weird characters that shows. It'll add a "$" to the end of each line, but other than that normal things will display normally and weird characters should stand out. For example, it displays Kamil's examples as ".bashrc$", ".bashrM-QM-^A$", and ".bM-PM-0shrc$".